# Can't Connect with Alfresco repo via aos

Tags: alfresco

You are my last hope... I have been looking for answers a long time ago.

I my trying to connect alfresco repo via aos. I push "Map network drive..." and i fill the textFields. The strange part of my story is that I can connect locally but i can't remotely. I have turned off my vm server firewall, just for case, but nothing.

I have edited alfresco-global.propertries, which I have append the following:

```
###############################
## Common Alfresco Properties #
###############################

dir.root=C:/ALFRES~1/alf_data

alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=https

share.context=share
share.host=127.0.0.1
share.port=8080
share.protocol=https

### database connection properties ###
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.username=alfresco
db.password=root
db.name=alfresco
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}
# Note: your database must also be able to accept at least this many             connections.  Please see your database documentation for instructions on how to configure this.
db.pool.max=275
db.pool.validate.query=SELECT 1

# The server mode. Set value here
# UNKNOWN | TEST | BACKUP | PRODUCTION
system.serverMode=UNKNOWN

### FTP Server Configuration ###
ftp.port=21
ftp.enabled=true

### RMI registry port for JMX ###
alfresco.rmi.services.port=50500
avm.rmi.service.port=0
avmsync.rmi.service.port=0
attribute.rmi.service.port=0
authentication.rmi.service.port=0
repo.rmi.service.port=0
action.rmi.service.port=0
deployment.rmi.service.port=0

### External executable locations ###
ooo.exe=C:/ALFRES~1/LIBREO~1/App/libreoffice/program/soffice.exe
ooo.enabled=true
ooo.port=8100
img.root=C:\\alfresco-community\\imagemagick
img.coders=${img.root}\\modules\\coders
img.config=${img.root}
img.gslib=${img.root}\\lib
img.exe=${img.root}\\convert.exe

jodconverter.enabled=false
jodconverter.officeHome=C:/ALFRES~1/LIBREO~1/App/libreoffice
jodconverter.portNumbers=8100

### Initial admin password ###
alfresco_user_store.adminpassword=329153f560eb329c0e1deea55e88a1e9

### E-mail site invitation setting ###
notification.email.siteinvite=false

### License location ###
dir.license.external=C:/ALFRES~1

### Solr indexing ###
index.subsystem.name=solr
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
solr.host=localhost 
solr.port.ssl=8443
##solr.port.ssl=443

### Allow extended ResultSet processing
security.anyDenyDenies=false

### Smart Folders Config Properties ###
smart.folders.enabled=false

### Remote JMX (Default: disabled) ###
alfresco.jmx.connector.enabled=false

### CIFS Server Configuration ###
# The tcpipSMB and netBIOSSMB beans have a platforms property that allow     their configuration to be targeted to Alfresco servers running on specific     platforms. The property is formatted as a comma-separated list of platform IDs. Valid platform IDs are windows,linux,solaris, macosx and aix.
cifs.platform=linux,solaris,macosx,windows
cifs.enabled= true
cifs.serverName=${localname}
cifs.broadcast=192.168.0.255
#An empty value indicates bind to all available network adapter
cifs.bindto=192.168.0.85
cifs.ipv6.enabled=true
cifs.hostannounce=true
cifs.pseudoFiles.enabled=false
#controls whether URL shortcuts or desktop actions are displayed on CIFS.
cifs.pseudoFiles.explorerURL.enabled=false
#Is the URL shortcut for alfresco explorer shown ?
#cifs.pseudoFiles.explorerURL.fileName=__Alfresco.url
#Name of CIFS URL for alfresco explorer
#cifs.pseudoFiles.shareURL.enabled=false
# Enable the use of asynchronous sockets/NIO code

cifs.disableNIO=false

# Disable the use of JNI code. Only currently affects Windows

cifs.disableNativeCode=false

# Session timeout, in seconds. Defaults to 15 minutes i.e. 900 seconds, to     match the default Windows client setting. Maximum is 3600.

# If no I/O is received within that time the session is closed by the server

cifs.sessionTimeout=3600

cifs.WINS.autoDetectEnabled=true

cifs.sessionDebug=false

# Can be mapped to non-privileged ports, then use firewall rules to forward     requests from the standard ports

cifs.tcpipSMB.port=1445

cifs.netBIOSSMB.sessionPort=1139

cifs.netBIOSSMB.namePort=1137

cifs.netBIOSSMB.datagramPort=1138

### Authentication Chain ###

authentication.chain=ldap1:ldap,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm

ldap.authentication.java.naming.read.timeout=15000

### Sync Settings ###

synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=true

synchronization.syncOnStartup=true

synchronization.syncWhenMissingPeopleLogIn=true

synchronization.import.cron=0 0 * * * ?

### SharePoint settings ###

vti.server.port=7070

vti.server.external.host=shp.parkmill.splatcooking.net

vti.server.external.port=443

vti.server.external.protocol=https
           vti.alfresco.alfrescoHostWithPort=https://alfresco.parkmill.splatcooking.net:443
vti.share.shareHostWithPort=https://alfresco.parkmill.splatcooking.net:443

vti.share.shareContext=/share

### replication ###

replication.enabled=true

### orphan removal ###

system.content.orphanProtectDays=1
alfresco.authentication.authenticationCIFS=true
```

Also I can connect via Browser but no hope with network drive mapping. What     is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Thx for your precious time.
I am waiting for your answers

Comment: Which are you using - Alfresco Office Services (AOS) or WebDav? (They're different!)

Comment: As I had written, i am using AOS.

Comment: Your question title says WebDav which isn't the same thing! Also, without the settings you're using, it's going to be very hard for us to help

Comment: Are you using AOS, or the older VTI? Only now your config file only mentions the old VTI settings, not the newer AOS ones...

Comment: i want to use AOS. These configs supposed to be for AOS use... Sadly, i am newbie and i can't understand all the configs... If you have some feedback to recommend i am all hears. Thx for your time

Comment: I'd suggest http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/aos-upgrade.html , http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/aos-config.html and http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/aos-troubleshooting.html for starters!

Comment: Also provide the exact URL you are using to try to map the drive to.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is the alfresco.host setting. You can connect locally, because it's looking at 127.0.0.1 (localhost). Your remote machine is trying to use 127.0.0.1 (which is local to that machine) and failing.

To fix this, update the alfresco.host and share.host properties to the IP or DNS name for the server on which Alfresco is installed.

Comment: This will also likely make "Edit in Microsoft Office" / "Edit Online" fail because it's attempting to retrieve the document from the machine on which you're editing (not the Alfresco server).